# Is phabricator Safe or it contains vulnebulities?

Tags: php, security, debugging, error-handling, xss

I am planning to use phabricator Do know know any existing vulnerabilities or security bugs that could affect my users. Like Xss etc.

here is source https://github.com/phacility/phabricator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are currently no known vulnerabilities, and Phabricator participates in HackerOne:
https://hackerone.com/phabricator